# How to make a dynamic report on weekly totals of fiscal year where fiscal year can change

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I would like to make a report able to be run for different fiscal years.

I am writing a report that has cumulative totals by week for our fiscal year.

Our fiscal year begins on July 1 and ends on June 30.  The first day of each week is Sunday.

Here's a snippet of what we have for the current fiscal year--2016

```
SELECT 
    (
    SELECT SUM(amount)
    FROM transactions
    WHERE transaction_date < '28-JUN-2015'
    ) AS 'x0',
    (
    SELECT SUM(amount)
    FROM transactions
    WHERE transaction_date < '05-JUL-2015'
    ) AS 'x1',
--keeps going until a week includes June 30.
FROM dual
```

I am lost as to how to proceed with writing this.  Here's what I'm thinking the logic should be:

Assuming I've passed the year as a variable (e.g. ":yr"),  I'd like to check if July 1 of :yr is Sunday.
----If July 1 is Sunday, then the first week will begin with July 1.
----If July 1 is not Sunday, then the first week will begin on the Sunday prior to July 1.

In both cases, subsequent weeks would begin on the following Sunday.
The loop would cease when the last week includes June 30 of the following year.

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at examples for [Calendaring Syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_sched.htm#BABFBCEF) of DBMS_SCHEDULER.
By default this is used for `SCHEDULER JOBS`, however I don't see any reason not using it for other purpose.

You can do it like this:

```
BEGIN
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_SCHEDULE('fiscal_year', repeat_interval => 'FREQ=YEARLY;BYDATE=0701');
END;


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GetFiscalYear(theYear IN TIMESTAMP DEFAULT LOCALTIMESTAMP) RETURN TIMESTAMP IS
    res TIMESTAMP;
BEGIN
     DBMS_SCHEDULER.EVALUATE_CALENDAR_STRING('FREQ=fiscal_year;BYDAY=-1 SUN', NULL, ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(theYear, 'YYYY'), -12), res);
    RETURN res;
END;
```

Example:

```
SELECT 
    TO_CHAR(GetFiscalYear(ADD_MONTHS(LOCALTIMESTAMP, -12)), 'yyyy-mm-dd fmDay') AS last_year,
    TO_CHAR(GetFiscalYear(), 'yyyy-mm-dd fmDay') AS this_year,
    TO_CHAR(GetFiscalYear(ADD_MONTHS(LOCALTIMESTAMP, 12)), 'yyyy-mm-dd fmDay') AS next_year
FROM dual;

LAST_YEAR            THIS_YEAR           NEXT_YEAR    
-------------------  ------------------  ----------------------
2014-06-29 Sunday    2015-06-28 Sunday   2016-06-26 Sunday

1 row selected.
```

**Update**

I even found a shorter way (i.e. without an extra schedule):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GetFiscalYear(theYear IN TIMESTAMP DEFAULT LOCALTIMESTAMP) RETURN TIMESTAMP IS
    res TIMESTAMP;
BEGIN
    -- Last Sunday of June 
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.EVALUATE_CALENDAR_STRING('FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=JUN;BYDAY=-1 SUN', NULL, ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(theYear, 'YYYY'), -12), res);
    RETURN res;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't mind rows instead of columns could you doing sum and group by week?
something like

```
select
sum (amount), trunc(transaction_date, 'WW')
group by trunc(transaction_date, 'WW')
order by 2
```

Comment: I certainly like the idea of rows vs columns (the end-user could just transpose the rows into columns for their Excel needs).  It looks like your solution figures that the day of week for July 1 is the first day of the week.  When I'm looking for is our first week should be the Sunday on or before July 1 of a given year.

Comment: wouldn't you just add an offset to transcaction date to accomadate for your fiscal year definition?